# Java Regex: Look behind group does not have an "obvious maximum length"

Tags: java, regex, quoting

I have a service running that uses regex sent to it and uses it to retrieve a value from a string.

I can create a main method inside the class and debug the regex `(?<=\\().+?(?=\\){1})` and it works perfectly.

However, as soon as I deploy it in tomcat to test remotely, I get the following exception:

```
Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 19
(?<=\\().+?(?=\\){1})
                   ^
```

Here is the function for parsing out a value that is being called:

```
private String parsePattern(String value, String pattern)
{
    String ret = "";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(value);
    while (m.find())
    {
        ret = m.group(0);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

What is going on that is causing it to compile in an app, but not work in a webapp?

EDIT:

This fails with any string, but the string currently being checked is: "(Group Camp Renovation)"

When called from `main`, the method returns "Group Camp Renovation", when called via webapp, it throws the exception.

Comment: `Pattern.compile()` works perfectly with the same regex when run from a main method. I know this is a Runtime Exception,  I want to know why it's only thrown in some circumstances.

Comment: I hope you aren't using `{1}` and that this is just a bad example on what you really have

Comment: Pattern.compile() wouldn't work unless I added the {1}

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Added the String that it is called with .

Comment: Above is the exact string being passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is - once again - quoting of strings in the Java code vs no quoting when read via some kind of input.

When you paste the string `(?<=\\().+?(?=\\){1})` like this:

```
String s1 = "(?<=\\().+?(?=\\){1})";
System.out.println(s1);
```

you will get this output

```
(?<=\().+?(?=\){1})
```

and this is what the regexp parser sees.

But when the same string is read via an `InputStream` (just as an example), nothing is altered:

```
String s1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
System.out.println(s1);
```

will print

```
(?<=\\().+?(?=\\){1})
```

Which means, that the `{1}` is attributed to the `(?=\\)` part and not to the `(?<=` part.

Comment: +1 Beautiful answer :) I had a blind spot for this issue and automatically doubled the backslashes in my example without thinking exactly that could be troubling OP.

Comment: Received your answer right as I figured it out myself. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have entered your pattern into [ideone](http://ideone.com/AIxErd) and the result is the same as your Tomcat's result:

```
System.out.println("aoeu".matches("(?<=\\\\().+?(?=\\\\){1})"));
```

Note how I have *doubled* all the backslashes in the string literal in order to have `Pattern.compile` receive the string you have in your error message.